# What does the "DRI_PRIME=2 program-name" command do?

Tags: gpu, hybrid-graphics, switchable-graphics

I use `DRI_PRIME=1 program-name` for running a program via discrete GPU on a notebook computer.

`DRI_PRIME=0 program-name` and `DRI_PRIME=2 program-name` gives the same result: program is run via integrated GPU.

Does the following command has any different effects on different systems (for example on 3 GPU installed desktop computers)?

```
DRI_PRIME=2 program-name
```

Comment: I never heard about 3-gpu switchable graphics. It makes no sense. So this does nothing.

Comment: Does ```DRI_PRIME=0 program-name``` command cause problems on single GPU installed computers (notebook and desktop)?

Comment: No, it doesn't. `DRI_PRIME` is a variable, nothing else. And it is 0 by default anyway ;-)